# What is a good way to integrate RSpec with another language such as Python or C#?

Tags: c#, python, ruby, testing, rspec

I wrote a Ruby Gem and other teams in the business will need to implement the same functionality in Python and C#.

I would like to run the exiting specs against the code in the other languages. Although it sounds like a difficult problem, the functionality of the gem is limited to formatting logs. The specs look like:

```
specify 'success' do
  expect{ logger.info('title', message) }.to output(expected).to_stdout
end
```

So, the entire test suite can be reduced to a set of expectations where the input is a string and a hash, and the output is a string.

It seems that there should be a easy to write a connector that would allow RSpec to talk to an instance of the code in another language.

Some possibilities include using HTTP or TCP, but I think that would introduce a significant code and complexity in both the specs and the app.

So, is there an established pattern or tool that will do this?

Comment: Please read "[ask]". "is there an established pattern or tool...?" is asking us to recommend an off-site tool, which is off-topic. Instead you need to search and try things then when you have a problem with your code ask a specific question about that problem. I'd recommend removing that aspect of the question. Asking about a pattern would be more on-topic.

Comment: Talking to a different host or server would introduce more than code complexity, it'd make the tests break if the required end-point was down. It'd also slow the tests. So while it's possible I wouldn't do it, at least for unit tests.

Comment: How is a tool off topic? It could include a library, gem or software. If I were asking how to do testing, wouldn't you suggest RSpec or Jasmine? Those are tools.

Comment: You're arguing against the SO community which decided that such questions are off-topic. You are welcome to take it to [meta], however your argument has been heard and decided against multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty way is just to execute python code like this :

```
%x(python -c "print 'hello I\\'m a logger'").include?('hello')
#=> true
```

For more advanced examples, you could use `IO.popen` or [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) :

```
require 'open3'

def run_python(code)
  Open3.popen3("python -c \"#{code}\"") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    {stdout: stdout.read, stderr: stderr.read}
  end
end

ten_warnings = %q|import logging
for i in range(10):
  logging.warning('Warning %d' % i)
|

describe 'Logger' do
  specify 'success' do
    expect(run_python(ten_warnings)[:stderr]).to include "Warning 5"
  end
end
```

It outputs :

```
.

Finished in 0.0266 seconds (files took 0.1499 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach.